# SpriteKit: what causes touchesMoved to stop getting called?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

`touchesMoved` within `GameScene.swift` is not getting called after a few invocations, usually three or four, even if we keep sliding a finger along the screen (i.e., never lifting the finger off the screen).

We created a simple project with nothing but code to print `touchesMoved`, and there is no problem. In other words, `touchesMoved` works as expected, continuing to get called as we slide the finger around.

Clearly, there is some code/configuration in the project causing `touchesMoved` to stop getting called after a few invocations (and without touchesEnd getting called). What things could cause this?

`touchesMoved` code that isn't getting called:

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {            
        let curTouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        let curPoint = curTouch.locationInView(self.view)
        println(curPoint)
}
```

Comment: You need to check is UIView in view hierarchy

Comment: @dimpiax thanks dima! what do you mean? this code is in GameScene.swift. why would UIView not be in the view hierarchy, meaning what code would cause this to happen so we can avoid this in the future?

Comment: can you upload your code or project on github?

Comment: just sent you an email with the link to the repo. thanks!

Comment: try to use minimize your code, to find real issue

Comment: To answer your question, touches moved gets called when a touch is detected and of the touch is moved.  It ends with a touchesEnded when you remove the touch.

Comment: thanks @meisenman but there is something happening because touchesmoved stops getting called even if touchesEnd doesn't get called.

Comment: Maybe your touch is being canceled. Have you tried to add touchesCanceled method to see if the touch goes there?

Comment: no great idea! will try it! didn't even know the function existed. :)

Comment: This bugs me too, but I think it happens not just 2-3 times, but maybe 10 times and then stops occuring, although it should still happen. Did you check if the touchesCanceled gets called after all?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case, was a gestureRecognizer in the SKView, after remove it everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem and Guilherme's answer is correct. This is the way to disable the gesture recognizers:

```
for recognizer in self.view!.gestureRecognizers!{
        self.view!.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
    }
```

And Objective-C:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```